# How to sync two TextBlock's background?

Tags: wpf, background, triggers, synchronization

I want to synchronize the background of two TextBlockes. For example, if the mouse is over any of the textblockes, I'd like to change the background color to the same for both textblockes. I know I can use this trigger to change one background:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

But how to sync them?

UPDATE: this is not working either:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Background="{Binding Path=Background, ElementName=tbHeader, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="A"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbHeader" Grid.Column="1" Text="B"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sync it by placing them in `ContentControl` and applying trigger on `ControlTemplate` like this -

```
  <Grid>
    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Rohit" x:Name="txt1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Vats" x:Name="txt2"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="TextBlock.IsMouseOver" SourceName="txt1" 
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Red" 
                                TargetName="txt1"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Red" 
                                TargetName="txt2"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TextBlock.IsMouseOver" SourceName="txt2" 
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Red" 
                                TargetName="txt1"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Red" 
                                TargetName="txt2"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ContentControl.Template>
    </ContentControl>
  </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [element to element binding](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/04/13/tutorial-binding-one-element-property-to-another/)

```
<TextBlock x:Name=textBlock1>
<TextBlock.Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>

<TextBlock Background={Binding Path=Background ElementName=textBlock1/><!--Background gets set from textBlock1-->
```

Comment: Well, that was what I thought initially, but it's not working. It works only if the mouse is over textBlock1, but it doesn't work if mouse is over textBlock2.

Comment: put the style into common place, or outside the TextBlock, and Mode=TwoWay

Comment: Just tried it...adding Mode=TwoWay to Background Binding doesn't work either. See full code from my update above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the 'correct' MVVM way, you should bind the mouse-over events/properties to the same property of a view model, and the background to the same property again, with a converter to convert it to the appropriate colour (or a style with templates).